# Non-traditional norm on Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follows:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{\alpha (x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2) - \beta (x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^2}$$
where $\alpha > n\beta$.

Is $f$ a norm?

It is clearly homogeneous. It is also non-negative since:
$(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^2 \leq n(x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)$, where equality holds if and only if $n=1$ or $x_1 = \ldots = x_n$. Therefore, it is also positive definite since $\alpha > n\beta$.
But I'm unable to prove/disprove the triangle inequality.

If not, are there sufficient conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that can ensure that $f$ is a norm?

Comment: What makes you think it could be a norm? What have you tried? Are you stuck on a specific part of the proof? Answers to these questions will help find a better answer.

Comment: @FedePoncio: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated with some details.

Comment: Let $n=2$ and plot the line $f^2(x, y)=1$ for various values of $\alpha, \beta$. If the resulting figure is convex, that is a norm. Otherwise it is not. This test should give you at least an idea of what is going on.

Comment: The procedure you should follow is to show that $f^2(x)=x^T A x$ where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Then $g(x,y)=x^T A y$ is an inner product so $f(x)=\sqrt{g(x,x)}$ is a norm. Identifying $A$ is pretty easy (if you have trouble with it, try doing $n=2$). Checking $A$ is symmetric is very easy. Checking that $A$ is positive definite is a bit more complicated especially if you don't know much linear algebra theory.

Comment: Giuseppe Negro's suggestion helps with seeing this approach because when you draw the figure what you get is an ellipse, which is always what you get with these $x^T A x$ inner products in 2D.

Comment: @Ian and GiuseppeNegro: Thanks for the wonderful ideas. I figured it out and will add an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment by Ian, the key idea is to show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x^T A x}$ for some symmetric positive definite matrix $A$.

Let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix and let $e$ be the $n$-dimensional vector of ones. Observe that:
$$f(x)^2 = \alpha x^T x - \beta (e^T x)^2 = x^T (\alpha I - \beta e e^T) x.$$

Therefore, $A = \alpha I - \beta e e^T$. According to the Sherman-Morrison formula, $A$ is positive definite if and only if $1 -\beta e^T (\alpha I)^{-1} e > 0$; that is, if and only if $\alpha > n\beta$.

Comment: Great solution!